# Error reading from Pipe to monitor SQL Server service through WCF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf

I am using WCF service channnel to monitor SQL Server service running on a remote PC. Running status of SQL Server service is uploading perfectly but when I stop the SQL Server service, then it breaks and throws an exception:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)

For other services, it works fine, only for SQL Server service it does not send status of service when service is in stopped state.

Is there any specific permission required to monitor SQL Server service?

SQL Server service name is `MYSQL$CMS`.

Comment: You should provide more information about what are you doing.

Comment: What are the *other services* it works fine for?

Comment: This issue has been resolved now.It was due to '$' character in servcie name. we use third party service to upload service status on cloud and $ is treated as special character on thirt party library.so now it is working because we have replaced $ with other character.Thanks